# PaginatedList - why I can't make ToList() in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created paginated list based on this tutorial:
http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part8.htm

It works but I don't understand 1 thing - I can't use ToList() in controller:

```
var paginatedDinners = new PaginatedList<Dinner>(upcomingDinners, page ?? 0, pageSize).ToList();

return View(paginatedDinners);
```

why? I have error: 
**System.InvalidCastException, cannot cast List to PaginatedList**

Without ToList() it works, why? PaginatedList inherits from List so why I can't use ToList()?

Comment: *Where* do you have that error? What is it complaining about? Does your view *expect* a `PaginatedList` model by any chance? (Look at the view declaration.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably your view has a line like this:

```
@model PaginatedList<Dinner>
```

This means that you cannot pass it anything other than a `PaginatedList<Dinner>`.

If you're using [this tutorial](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part8.htm), the implementation of `PaginatedList<Dinner>` that they've provided inherits from `List<T>` so you may be able to get it working by changing your `@model` declaration to this:

```
@model List<Dinner>
```

But of course, this will not work if you're using any properties of the `PaginatedList<T>` class in your view.

Answer (score 0):

`PaginatedList` is inherited from `List`, but whenever you expect a `PaginatedList` it is inaccurate to pass a `List`. You can either modify your code to have a `List` or pass a `PaginatedList`.